Jena-Fuseki: Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html which is not recognized for SELECT queries
I'm trying to make this SPARQL query using Jena-Fuseki Version 5.1.0 (SPARQL Endpoint: /ds/sparql | Content type (SELECT): JSON | Content type (GRAPH): Turtle), but gives me an error.
code

PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX nobel: <http://data.nobelprize.org/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?year ?prizeName
WHERE{
    SERVICE <https://data.nobelprize.org/sparql>{
        ?person rdf:type nobel:Laureate;
            rdfs:label ?name;
            nobel:nobelPrize ?prize.
        ?prize rdfs:label ?prizeName;
            nobel:year ?year.
        FILTER (lang(?prizeName) = 'en' && ?year = 1901)
    }
}

error
And the error is:

Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html which is not recognized for SELECT queries.
Status code 200 OK, Method GET, Request Headers: {Accept=[application/sparql-results+json, application/sparql-results+xml;q=0.9, text/tab-separated-values;q=0.7, text/csv;q=0.5,application/json;q=0.2,application/xml;q=0.2,/;q=0.1]}

endpoints
I've searched for nobelprize.org's endpoint and I only find these two:

https://data.nobelprize.org/sparql


https://data.nobelprize.org/snorql

The problem is that both still return the same error. Does anybody know if there's another one?
expectation
What I-m trying to do is to retrieve a list of laureates and, then, do a federated query to wikidata, but I-m having problems with nobelprize.org response.
tried
I've also tried to add 'force=true' as a URL parameter (see JENA: Endpoint returned Content-Type: text/html) but I don't know how to do it (I've added it directly to the endpoint - as ~/sparql?force=true - but it still fails).
When doing the same query in nobelprize's sparql page, deleting the line where it says SERVICE (and the corresponding closing curly brace), it works.
note
IMPORTANT: I need to do the query using Jena-Fuseki (or similar) because I must do a federated query to wikidata and if I do it from nobelprize's sparql page, it fails. The opposite (doing a federated query from wikidata) also fails (it says it is not allowed).

Please show how you are making the query. It look like the request is going to one of the UI pages.

RobV's answer is correct. The endpoint is: https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql
AndyS is right and the query (correcting the quotes) curl --data-urlencode "query=SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 1" https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql works
With respect to UninformedUser's answer Setting QuerySendMode to asPost in Jena also fails, setting QuerySendMode to asPostForm does work., I didn't know how to do it so I posted another question Jena-Fuseki: Set per-query execution context

The URL you included in your question appears to only be the web interface to their SPARQL Endpoint, not the actual endpoint.
By running a query from there and looking at the network activity in my web browsers developer tools I can see that the actual SPARQL query gets submitted to https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql
So try modifying your code to use that endpoint instead and you should hopefully get things working

Thanks for the answer. I've changed the endpoint to  https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql, but it returns a "Bad request" error. I'm still trying to guess what's wrong...

it's a bit strange, the GET request Jena does send is valid, but it leads to an error. Also using curl with the URL encoded string it fails. When I encode the query with some external tool which also encodes slashes etc. it works with curl.

Setting QuerySendMode to asPost in Jena also fails, setting QuerySendMode to asPostForm does work.

Thanks for the comments. With respect to the second comment, I'm a newbie with Jena and have no clue about how to set "QuerySendMode" to "asPostForm". How do you do it?

With respecto to the first one: I've done two curl requests, but none worked. This is one curl -H "Accept: text/turtle" --data-urlencode "query@jena_nobelprizea_query_test.rq" https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql -v and the other one is similar, but encoding with the same URL that you provided and then appending the result to curl -H "Accept: text/turtle" https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql?query=

curl --data-urlencode 'query=SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 1' 'https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql' works
